# Edit Route No Matches Routing Error GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hey guys I am using Rails 5. I am trying to let my users edit there info, password etc but when I go to this route.

http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/edit/1

The error I get is 
No route matches [GET] "/users/edit/1"

I do have a user with an ID of 1 and I have checked in my rails console to verify.

I have an edit template, and the edit controller and the edit method in the controller but its just not working. What am I doing wrong? All help is welcome, thank you!

ROUTES

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root  'pages#home'
  get  'pages/tierlist', to: 'pages#tierlist'

  resources :articles

  get 'signup', to: 'users#new'
  resource :users, except:[:new]

end
```

USERSCONTROLLER

```
class UsersController <ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the OP-OR-Nah Community #{@user.username}"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end


end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit your info</h1>
```

Also when I rake routes this is what I get back

```
rake routes |grep edit
  edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
    edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format)        users#edit
```

Comment: rake routes |grep edit
  edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
    edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format)        users#edit

Comment: WOW that was it lol are you kidding me, i forgot the s. Thank you!

Comment: Post it as an answer so i can rep you please :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your file that is breaking the route.

Should be

```
resources :users, except: [:new]
```

That route typically should look like

```
"/users/:id/edit"
```

when you run rake:routes.

Answer (score 0):

Default url for edit is `pluralize_model_name/id/edit` so `users/1/edit`. Anyway, you wrote `resource` and not `resources` so I think you have not that route. `resource` is a different method that generate something like

```
GET       /user/new
GET       /user
GET       /user/edit
PATCH/PUT /user
DELETE    /user
POST      /user
```